# Implicit Data Type Conversion in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldatatypes

Is the statement true?

Comparison between character value and a number value always implicitly converts the character value to the number data type.

Comment: "always implicitly converts" is strictly speaking false, because it implies that the conversion always takes place. The correct way to state this is "always **attempts to** implicitly convert" - the attempt may fail, in which case you get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's true.

[The manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Type-Comparison-Rules.html#SQLRF-GUID-98BE3A78-6E33-4181-B5CB-D96FD9DC1694) pretty much contains the same sentence

> Implicit Data Conversion
> ...
> ...
>
> - When comparing a character value with a numeric value, Oracle converts the character data to a numeric value.

Comment: Obviously the manual is imprecise: "Oracle converts" only if it can. If it can't, it throws an error. When comparing 'x' to 3, Oracle doesn't convert the character data to a numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's true, and it can be kind of annoying if you have a `VARCHAR2` column with mixed characters and numbers and you're trying to select one of the numbers. See this example:

```
create table t1 ( c1 varchar2(10));
insert into t1 values ('x');
insert into t1 values ('1');

select * from t1 where c1 = 1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3d880/1